# R removing citations from strings in data

Tags: r, string, citations, tidyr

I had pulled tax data from Wikipedia and was working on recombining it, but I'm having trouble removing the citation tags from the data (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_tax_rates#Countries). 
At first, I tried using strsplit on the [ to remove it, but this is what I got:

```
URL <- "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_tax_rates#Countries"

library(XML) 
taxes <- readHTMLTable(URL, which=2) 

matrix(unlist(strsplit(taxes$Country, "\\[")), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
[,1]                       [,2]                      
[1,] "Albania"                  "1]"                      
[2,] "Algeria"                  "3]"                      
[3,] "Andorra"                  "citation needed]"        
[4,] "Angola"                   "1]"                      
[5,] "Argentina"                "Armenia"                 
[6,] "1]"                       "Aruba"
```

Ultimately I want to remove the citations (numbered or "citation needed" and the brackets surronding them). I was hoping to have the numbers in the second column and country names in the first so I could just keep the names, but it mixes the columns when there is no footnote. I also looked at using `cSplit` but didn't have any success with that approach either. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you provide us with a minimal working example? Also, I have the sense that these '[citation needed]' and other tags are only the start of your worries: a lot of other cleaning will be necessary. Maybe the fastest is just to do it by hand.

Comment: Give `library(XML); readHTMLList(URL)` a try.  Looks like you're looking at element `[[12]]` here

Comment: Also, with this particular string it looks like `t(sapply(strsplit(x, "\\[|\\]"), "length<-", 2))` might be what you want.

Comment: You beat me to it, I was just about to add the readHTMLTable command. Sorry about leaving that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this regex will work:

```
URL <- "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_tax_rates#Countries"

library(XML) 
taxes <- readHTMLTable(URL, which=2) 

gsub("\\[(\\d+|citation needed)\\]", "", taxes$Country)
```

Comment: Great! It cleans everything but the [citation needed] which, should be doable in a similar manner. I had found an html tag remover function that was somewhat similar, but this worked better. Thanks!

Comment: @Richard I deduced it and used the example the poster attempted to give.  I'm going to beef up their question with what I figured out.

Comment: I'd say you deduced that quite nicely :) Second table, column 1 is the culpret

Comment: @TylerRinker, `gsub('\\[[^]]*\\]', '', taxes$Country)` would be fine here =)